# Ruby OpenGL: How to load Bitmap textures and put them on the 3D Objects?

Tags: ruby, opengl

I just started programming with Ruby-OpenGL.
I translated the Nehe Tutorial to a Renderer Class and it works fine showing some simple 3D objects.
Now I want to put some textures on these objects.
I have a "texture.bmp" but how to place it over my objects?
This is my Renderer Class:

```
module RGLEngine
    require "rubygems"
    require "gl"
    require "glu"
    require "glut"
    require "mathn"
    require "yaml"

    class Renderer
        include Gl
        include Glu
        include Glut

        attr_reader :width, :height

        def initialize
            @width = 640 # to be loaded from config.yaml
            @height = 480
        end
        def render
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
            glLoadIdentity
            glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.0, -6.0)
            # Draw Poylgons
            # ...
      # uncomment this for a simple example
            #glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            #   glVertex3f( 0.0,  1.0, 0.0)
            #   glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
            #   glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
            #glEnd
            glutSwapBuffers
        end
        def idle
            glutPostRedisplay
        end
        def reshape(width, height)
            if height == 0
                height = 1
            end
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
            glLoadIdentity
            gluPerspective(45.0, width / height, 0.1, 100.0)
        end
        def realize!
            glutInit
            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
            glutInitWindowSize(@width, @height)
            glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
            window = glutCreateWindow("RGLEngine alpha")
            glutDisplayFunc(method(:render).to_proc)
            glutReshapeFunc(method(:reshape).to_proc)
            glutIdleFunc(method(:idle).to_proc)
            glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0)
            glClearDepth(1.0)
            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
            glLoadIdentity
            gluPerspective(45.0, @width / @height, 0.1, 100.0)
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
            glutMainLoop()
        end
    end
end

RGLEngine::Renderer.new.realize!
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL doesn't know anything about file formats, so you're going to need something to load your bmp into memory before you can call glTexImage2D.

Edit: here are some resources: [textures](http://ruby-opengl.rubyforge.org/tutorial.html#textures) and maybe [image loading](http://rubygame.org/wiki/Image_viewer_demo)